# Microsoft apps are not saving my logins anymore

Tags: windows-10, login

After updating Windows 10 a few weeks ago, all my default folders links (including Documents, Desktop and Download) were changed to a default user folder which Windows could not access (I do not know why or how). Anyway after searching the internet I fixed that by resetting their links back to the right folders. (Properties => Location => Restore Default) All my Firefox setting were lost as well but syncing helped me with that.

Problem is, after that event non of Microsoft apps including Skype, One Drive and Visual Studio keep me logged in. I have to login to each one of them after every shutdown. (Sign out is fine though)

My guess is that the folder where Windows keeps information related to logins has a wrong link as well, but I do not know where that is or how to reset that too.

How can I fix this?

---

I have tried Logging out and in again.

I have tried checking registry section related to user directors, it seemed fine but if there is any suggestions I will try them.

I do not have any backup or roll back points from before the problem started.

I know creating a new user will probably fix the issue but I have so many apps and setting installed to "this user only", it will almost mean installing windows from scratch.

Windows own login works fine.

Windows Version: 1909 (Build 18.363.720)

Comment: Did you by any chance log into a temporary profile (Windows sometimes does this) which you then adjusted?

Comment: @John No, I do not remember doing so.

Comment: If that is the case, then you need to create a new Windows User Profile. Not even a Repair Install will fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you logged in with your regular profile (not a temporary profile), then the profile is damaged and you must create a new on.

The well-known Windows Repair Install will not correct a damaged profile.